# Term for One person performing a whole Arrangement with nothing else accompanying (As a Cover)

Tags: composition, terminology, performing, ornaments, performance-practice

Like how "Unplugged Version" means the Original Song has been performed with 0 usage of technology-stuff (other than Microphone) [No editing, Acoustic Instruments only, No Faders, No Compressors],
What's the name given to a Version in which One Person is emulating the whole song, playing as many parts he/she can at once?

For example, take Hotel California, one person is playing all the parts written in the below snap. [image]

Well basically a cover but only one person and he/she is playing as many parts possible to bringing in as many elements as possible.

(Hoping the question belongs here, not english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: One man band..?

Comment: "A whole arrangement"?! "Playing all the parts"?! He's singing, playing a guitar and tapping his foot. Anyone can do that! Dylan can probably do any of his songs without a band, AND throw in a mouth organ! It's called doing a song **on your own**.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian , I only took an example, maybe this wasn't a good example.

Comment: @Tim So... if 'One-man-band' is the only word for the performer, I wish to know what the term would be for the performance, like for titling the performance.

Comment: "Herb Alpert and the Tijuana Brass"

Comment: If one person plays, it's technically called a solo.

Answer (score 2):

The guy in the Hotel California is playing a 3 guitar song on one guitar.  Try to play it, it's not easy reading.  Jeff Beck does a solo guitar cover of the Beatles' *entire* Sergeant Pepper album.  So maybe "Beck style solo guitar cover arrangement."

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a solo performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has come up with anything better, my suggestion is: "A singer accompanying themself".